# Retrieve contact information given its ID (Android)

Tags: android

I'm trying to retrieve specific contact information (such as phone number, name and e-mail) given its `ID` or its `LOOKUP`.

Firstly, I read all the current contacts data with this code:

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.SORT_KEY_PRIMARY + " ASC");
```

Once the user has selected an specific contact, I pass its `id` through the putExtra method to another activity, which is intended to read and display the information of that contact.

```
Intent contactDetails = new Intent(ContactsMainActivity.this, ContactsDialogActivity.class);
contactDetails.putExtra("ID",id);
startActivity(contactDetails);
```

The problem arises here. In `ContactsDialogActivity`, I want to retrieve the information of that contact by searching by the `id`:

```
cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, 
                ContactsContract.Contacts._ID + " = ?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)},
                ContactsContract.Contacts.SORT_KEY_PRIMARY + " ASC");
```

But that query always throws me a -1 index (it does not find that ID), which returns the following error:

```
07-17 11:23:14.637 27073-27073/gib.bcimobilephone E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                Process: gib.bcimobilephone, PID: 27073
                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{gib.bcimobilephone/gib.bcimobilephone.ContactsDialogActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2924)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2985)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1635)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
                                                                 Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1
                                                                    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:460)
                                                                    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
                                                                    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
                                                                    at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:137)
                                                                    at gib.bcimobilephone.ContactsDialogActivity.onCreate(ContactsDialogActivity.java:94)
                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6912)
                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2877)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2985) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1635) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It sounds like your query matches none of the elements. `-1` is commonly returned if there was nothing found. You should check if it is `> -1` before trying to access the array at that index position

Comment: Yeah, I suppose that. But I think that I am not doing the search correctly, because that ID was previously returned by the first query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Assuming you have a valid contactID, you can do this:

Cursor result = managedQuery(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, 
         ContactsContract.Contacts._ID +" = ?", 
         new String[]{contactID}, null);      
if (result.moveToFirst()) {

    for(int i=0; i< result.getColumnCount(); i++){
        Log.i("CONTACTSTAG", result.getColumnName(i) + ": "
        + result.getString(i));
    }         
}
You will have to change the ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI and the where clause to the table that you are querying. The above code will print out a bunch of general info about a contact.
```